# Timezone in nodejs, typeorm and postgresql

Tags: typescript, postgresql, timezone, typeorm

I have a problem with the time of my database records. The database time zone is ok, in the region I need. Not in the api, I always have to put the process.env.tz in the region I need. Even so, I can't make it go to the correct time, it always goes 3 hours longer. I'm using nodejs with ts and typeorm, the database is postgresql. I couldn't find help on github either. Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe the api displaying 3h longer is because the server where your app is been hosted might be alined with GMT time. I would think your data is been stored as date or unix and when date field is consumed the server reads it its own way, GMT.  I would try to use a JS library on the api side that can convert you postgresql data onto you desire timezone.

Comment: api both running local and vps has this problem at the time